# Unable to get table on this website by using python web scraping

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get the table on this website on live basis & unable download csv as the link is hidden in java script. Selenium is also not able access this website - https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain.

Comment: Please post the code you used and the errors you ran into

Answer (score 0):

You can use beautifulsoup for scraping and get the table by id [here is the doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)